# Problem with route in Ajax using Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to get a list of countries with their cities using Select2 with Jquery.

At the time of creating a post with their respective country and city, I don't have a problem, but at the time of editing the post I miss the following error:

http: //imperial.test/dashboard/posts/40/edit/getStates/6 (Not Found)

D:\laragon\www\Imperial\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php # 179

**Routes:**

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => 'dashboard', 
'namespace' => 'Admin', 
'middleware' => 'auth'], 
function(){

    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', [
        'names' => [
            'index' => 'dashboard.posts.index',
            'create' => 'dashboard.posts.create',
            'store' =>  'dashboard.posts.store',
            'edit'  =>  'dashboard.posts.edit',
            'update' => 'dashboard.posts.update',
            'destroy' => 'dashboard.posts.destroy',
        ],
    ]);

    Route::get('posts/create/getStates/{id}', 'PostsController@getStates');
    Route::get('posts/create/getCities/{id}', 'PostsController@getCities');

    Route::get('posts/edit/getStates/{id}', 'PostsController@getStates');
    Route::get('posts/edit/getCities/{id}', 'PostsController@getCities');

    Route::get('images/posts/{id}/avatar/{image}', [
        'uses' => 'PostsController@postProfileAvatar',
    ]);
```

});

**My Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name="country_id"]').on('change',function(){

    var country_id = $(this).val();

    if(country_id)
    {
        $.ajax({

            url: '/edit/getStates/'+country_id,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);

                $('select[name="state_id"]').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $('select[name="state_id"]')
                                .append('<option value="'+key+'">' + value + '</option>');
                });
            }

        });
    } else {
        $('select[name="state_id"]').empty();
    }

});

$('select[name="state_id"]').on('change',function(){
    var state_id = $(this).val();
    if(state_id)
    {
        $.ajax({

            url: '/edit/getCities/'+state_id,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);

                $('select[name="city_id"]').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $('select[name="city_id"]').append('<option value="'+key+'">' + value + '</option>');
                })
            }

        });
    }else {
        $('select[name="city_id"]').empty();
    }
});
```

});

N' in the blade if the script path is registered:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/worldedit.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this error, I tried it in a separate project without using Route :: group and prefixes and I did it with GET routes and it worked, so I deduce that the problem is in the ajax route

Answer (score 0):

Your route is under a group with prefix `dashboard`, so shouldn't it be

```
url: '/dashboard/posts/edit/getStates/'+ country_id
```

Instead of just

```
url: '/edit/getStates/'+country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are viewing a post your current address is

```
http: //imperial.test/dashboard/posts/40
```

and your javascript has this url (relative address)

```
url: '/edit/getStates/'+country_id,
```

So ajax call actually get this url:

```
http: //imperial.test/dashboard/posts/40/edit/getStates/6
```

While you are defining route (in laravel web.php) for

```
  http: //imperial.test/dashboard/posts/edit/getStates/{id}
```

So you get not found error.

Define your routes as

```
Route::get('posts/{postid}/edit/getStates/{id}', 'PostsController@getStates');
Route::get('posts/{postid}/edit/getCities/{id}', 'PostsController@getCities');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the route helper to get the route by name. In this case, you can do the following:

In the html "select" element:

For example, suppose you have a route called "cities.list" that retrieves all cities in this state:

```
<select name="state_id" data-route="{{ route('cities.list', ['id' => ':id']) }}" >
```

So, in the js script just use that route as follows:

```
    ....
    var select_state = $('select[name="state_id"]'); // or $(this)     
    var route = select_state.data('route')
    route = route.replace(':id', select_state.val())

    $.ajax({

        url: route,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
    ....
```

Did you get the idea?